# Getting Data out of a container

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote a function that creates new Input fields based on the number of input fields needed. That code is below.

```
for (i=0;i<number;i++){
    container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Guest " + (i+1)));
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.id = "Guest" + i;
    container.appendChild(input);
    container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    console.log(i.value);
```

It creates a new Id for each input field. In the function below,depending on the number you set for `i`, the function creates a generated message.

```
function sendInput ()
{
    var guestNames = document.getElementById("Guest").value
    var personName = document.getElementById("people").value;
    var eventType = document.getElementById("event").value;
    var date = document.getElementById("date").value;
    var output = "Dear " + guestNames + " You have been invited to " + personName + "'s " + eventType + " on " + date +  " Thank you for coming!!";
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = output.repeat(i);
}
```

The problem is it is not collecting the data for `guestNames`. I am pretty new to JS but have searched and cannot find a solution to my problem. Any feedback wouls be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDs are difficult to work with in a dynamic environment, classes are generally the simplest solution. This code will convert your inputs to have classes, then loop through them and collect the names.

So change:

```
input.id = "Guest" + i;
```

to

```
input.setAttribute("class","guest");
```

And change

```
var guestNames = document.getElementById("Guest").value
```

to:

```
var guests = document.querySelectorAll(".guest");
var guestNames = [];

guests.forEach(function(el){
  guestNames.push(el.value);
});

guestNames = guestNames.join(",");
```

If you are wanting a message for EACH guest, then you would use the below function:

```
function sendInput ()
{
    var personName = document.getElementById("people").value;
    var eventType = document.getElementById("event").value;
    var date = document.getElementById("date").value;

    var guests = document.querySelectorAll(".guest");
    var guestNames = [];

   document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = "";

    guests.forEach(function(el){
     document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += "Dear " + el.value + " You have been invited to " + personName + "'s " + eventType + " on " + date +  " Thank you for coming!!";
    });
}
```

Comment: This what I wanted to say :) gj.

Comment: As far as I understand OP wants to welcome every guest with their specific name, so imho `id`s make sense. But I admit that they are not clear about the final purpose, so let's wait for feedback ;)

Comment: Yes this has been helpful but like Robert said, I would like to make it where every time it prints the welcome line. It is each person's name.

Comment: @zlucas03 I updated my answer before you commented, I have a new `sendInput ` function in there

Answer (score 0):

You try to get node by id `var guestNames = document.getElementById("Guest").value`
But all nodes have a different id, like a `Guest0`,`Guest1` etc. I am trying to write my own code, but your snippet isn't full. I hope I helped you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, when you try to fetch the guest name

```
var guestNames = document.getElementById("Guest").value
```

you won't get any element for two reasons because there's no element with id "Guest". In fact you generate them in the form `"GuestN"`

```
`input.id = "Guest" + i;`
```

You probably want to add a parameter `i` to `sendInput ()` function, so that internally you can concatenate it to `Guest` as you did above and get the correct element with `getElementById()`.

Comment: FWIW, semicolons are actually optional as a line terminator. They only really are needed for packing/minimizing the javascript.

Comment: @imvain2 sorry, I often fall in this trap due to my C-ish background. I corrected it. Thanks  for the report.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incomplete (as far as I can tell).

1. You do not specify the following elements anywhere:
   'container', 'guest', 'people', 'event', 'data' or 'output'
   I assume they should be defined somewhere in the HTML section (not provided)
2. To be able to create the variable displays, you need to define the 'container' you wish to initialize it before it is used in the for() loop that follows.
   Example: var container = document.getElementById('container');
3. Within the loop, console.log(i.value) is invalid as i is not an element that has been assigne a value to display.  It is a counter of the for() loop.
4. The function of sendInput(), I assume, is to collect the information from the user for each "Guest#" created by the first loop of your code.  However you try to collect from "Guest" which has not been defined.  For a number of 5, the collections should be for "Guest1", "Guest2", "Guest3", "Guest4", "Guest5".  "Guest" only can not be found anywhere in your loop creation.  Same goes for 'people, 'event' and 'date' which are referenced for value collection, but there are no elements named as such.
5. Not exactly sure why you are mixing DOM creation techniques (???).
   You create the number of element for the guest, but then output the results with .innerHTML.  You should use the DOM creation method, but I have used your code as you indicated you are a beginner.

Here is some (partially) corrected code that you can continue on with.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><title> Test Page </title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width,initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes"/>

<!-- link rel="stylesheet" href="common.css" media="screen" -->
<style>

</style>

</head><body>
<input type="text" value="5/28/2020" id="date">
<pre id='container'></pre>
<button id="report">Report</button>
<pre id='output'></pre>

<script>
console.clear();

function init() {
  var number = 5;
  var container = document.getElementById('container');

  for (i=0;i<number;i++) {
    var value = "Guest " + (i+1)+' ';
    container.appendChild(document.createTextNode(value));

    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.id = "Guest" + i;
    input.value = value;

    container.appendChild(input);
    container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    console.log(i); // .value);
  }
  document.getElementById('report').addEventListener('click',sendInput);
} init();

  function sendInput () {
    var date = document.getElementById("date").value,
        output = document.getElementById('output'),
        info = '';
        var guestNames = [...document.querySelectorAll('#container input')];  // alert(guestNames.length);

    for (let i=0; i<guestNames.length; i++) {
      info = `Dear ${guestNames[i].value}:\nYou have been invited to XXX's EVENT on ${date}\nThank you for coming!!\n\n`;
      output.innerHTML += info;
    }
//    var guestNames = document.getElementById("Guest").value
//    var personName = document.getElementById("people").value;
//    var eventType = document.getElementById("event").value;
//    var output = "Dear " + guestNames + " You have been invited to " + personName + "'s " + eventType + " on " + date +  " Thank you for coming!!";
//    output = `Dear ${guestNames}:\nYou have been invided to XXX's EVENT on ${date}\nThank you for coming!!`;
//    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = output.repeat(i);
  }

</script>

</body></html>
```